# How to avoid Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am initialising `Map? data`, I am getting this error `Null check operator used on a null value` initially before the data is loaded. How to avoid this error and load the data.

If I remove the null operator and initialise it with empty map `Map data = {}`  I am getting this error  `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

my code

```
List cards = [];
Map? data;

getData(){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserData').doc(getUid()).collection('TransactionData').get().then((value){
      value.docs.forEach((element) {
        cards.add(element.data());
      });
      setState(() {
        data = cards[0];
      });
    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
}

//in my build method

CardSelector(
   cards: cards.map((context) => CardPage(context)).toList(),
   mainCardWidth: _width,
   mainCardHeight: _width * 0.63,
   mainCardPadding: -16.0,
   onChanged:(i){
      setState(() {
         data = cards[i];
      });
}),

Expanded(child: AmountPage(data!))

class AmountPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map _amount;

  AmountPage(this._amount);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('_amount: $_amount');

    var textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    var padding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 24.0);
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      itemCount: (_amount['transaction'] as List).length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        if (i == 0) {
          return Padding(
            padding: padding,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Balance', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                // Text(_amount['amount']),
                SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                Text('Today', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }
        var transactions = _amount['transaction'][i - 1];
        return Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.shopping_cart, size: 24.0, color: Colors.blueGrey[600]),
              SizedBox(width: 16.0),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(transactions['transactionId']),
                    Text(transactions['transactionDate'], style: textTheme.caption)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Text(transactions['amount'])
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

how to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide code pointing out the issue

Comment: how do you pass value to your map?

Comment: could you please also include AmountPage?

Answer (score 0):

For `Map? data` you need to check

```dart
if(data!=null && && data.isNotEmpty){
  //do your stuff 
}
```

For `Map data = {}` case do

```dart
 if(data.isNotEmpty) YourWidget();
```

For range error, I suspect `cards[i];`

try with

```dart
if(i<cards.length){
   data = cards[i];
}
```

For future case, it is first index

```dart
if(cards.isNotEmpty){
   data = cards[0];
}
```

Comment: For widget `if(data!=null)Expanded(child: AmountPage(data!))`

Comment: i tried by checking the null i am getting this error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Comment: did you try with `i<cards.length`, for your case, `if(data.isNotEmpty) data = cards[0];`

Comment: yes i tried, same error i got for this.

Comment: There  will be two changes on card reading, is there any other places you are using index to get data?

Comment: inside the CardSelector, which is an package https://pub.dev/packages/card_selector

Comment: Try checking `_amount['transaction']` is null or empty, like `itemCount: (_amount['transaction'] as List? ??[]).length + 1,`

Comment: still same error

Comment: You can commenting  widgets or deluging to find the specific part

Comment: ok. i wil try that.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `Map? data`, You should make suer it is not null, for example do this:

```
if(data != null){
  print('${data!['something']}');
}
```

or :

```
Text('${data?['something'] ?? ''}');
```

also these in your AmountPage:

```
var transaction = _amount['transaction'] as List ?? [];
itemCount: transaction.length + 1,

var transactions = transaction.isNotEmpty ? transaction[i - 1]: {};
```

Comment: i tried by checking the null i am getting this error `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Comment: which one you try?

Comment: this first one `if(data!=null) Expanded(child: AmountPage(data!))`

Comment: could you include what is inside AmountPage?

Comment: i have updated.

Comment: still same error.